# Cursor.Position doesn't set correct point with Array/Variable

Tags: vb.net

I have an array of three points with this:

```
Public Points(2) As Point
```

I set the value of Point(0):

```
Points(0) = PointToScreen(Label1.Location)
```

When I go to set the Cursor Position using this, the position is at the upper left corner, or 0, 0

```
Cursor.Position = Points(0)
```

I have also tried this with no luck:

```
Cursor.Position = New Point(Points(0).X, Points(0).Y)
```

Also, I have confirmed that Point(0) does contain a value by showing it in a text box.

What am I doing wrong? I appreciate any replies. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The assignment of a Point should work alright.

But note that as you call it,  `PointToScreen` is a method of the Form.
If Label1 lies directly on the form, then `PointToScreen(Label1.Location)` will work, but not if it is in another container.

If Label1 lies on the form, then your call is equivalent to this:

```
Cursor.Position = Label1.Parent.PointToScreen(Label1.Location)
```

But that does work only if `Label1.Parent = Form1`, which is probably not the case in your situation - so you need to use the line above, which can be cut down further to this:

```
Cursor.Position = Label1.PointToScreen(New Point(0, 0))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position = New Point(100, 100)
```